# Running a script according to shebang line

Tags: unix, shebang

I've got a script on my computer named `test.py`. What I've been doing so far to run the program is type `python test.py` into the terminal.

Is there a command on Unix operating systems that doesn't require the user to specify the program he/she uses to run the script but that will instead run the script using whichever program the shebang line is pointing to?

For example, I'm looking for a command that would let me type `some_command test.txt`into the terminal, and if the first line of `test.txt` is `#!/usr/bin/python`, the script would be interpreted as a python script, but if the first line is `#!/path/to/javascript/interpreter`, the the script would be interpreted as javascript.

Comment: Can you please share your use case why you need such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default behavior of the terminal (or just executing a file in general) all you have to do is make the script executable with

```
chmod u+x test.txt
```

Then (assuming `text.txt` is in your current directory) every time you type

```
./text.txt
```

It will look at the sh-bang line and use the program there to run `text.txt`.

Comment: The terminal is not involved at all. Even the shell is just passing the file to the kernel via one of the `exec*` system calls.

Comment: @tripleee I know that, but since the OP doesn't know about sh-bang lines I made the judgement call that it would be better to describe it in terms of what they'll observe rather than how it actually works.  Had the OP demonstrated more experience with unix, I would have described it in terms of ``execve`` for the most accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to duplicate built-in functionality, try this.

```
#!/bin/sh
x=$1
shift
p=$(sed -n 's/^#!//p;q' "$x" | grep .) && exec $p "$@"
exec "$x" "$@"
echo "$0: $x: No can do" >&2
```

Maybe call it `start` to remind you of the similarly useful Windows command.